# How do I make a Facebook-like chat/

Tags: ajax, facebook, websocket, chat

I want to make a application where users can make an account and say where they have travelled. Adding user etc. I also want them to interact with each other, with a private chat. Not messaging, but chatting. I have looked into this and this is what I have found:

-Websockets
Not the standard. I have made a chat with this once, but the chats are not saved when you leave the page.

-Long polling
This might be the best option, but I don't know which frameworks can be used to make this possible.

-AJAX
This is the most simple thing to do, but I am afraid that this will stress the server and the website will be very slow.

As I have mentioned before, it would be nice if the saved messages would be saved and could be seen by the users (like Facebook does). My question is: what should I make this chat with? AJAX would not be the solution, since the server would overload. Does Facebook load the messages from a database, or do they save it like "conversation12345.txt" and load it?

Comment: You asked quite a few questions there, what technologies are available to you? If you have experience with ASP.NET look into SignalR

Comment: I have experience with ASP.net (C#), but I use a Ubuntu server, so no support voor ASP.net...